# Copy first N files which start with 'a' 'c' or 'e' from one folder to another in Linux

Tags: linux, terminal, copy, conditional-statements, cp

I have many files in specified directory. For instance, I want to copy 6 of them to one location.
I came up with this:

```
find . -type f |head -6| xargs cp /specified_dir/[ace]* -t /target_loc
```

The problem is that every file which starts with 'a' 'c' 'e' is copied. There should be first 6 files, but I receive 8 (4 with 'a',  3 with 'c' and 1 with 'e').
I was wondering, if there is a way to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your command you get only the 6 first results from `find` (which are not the files starting with `[ace]`) but what you finally execute is this command:

```
cp /specified_dir/[ace]* -t /target_loc <file_argument>
```

which copies all the `[ace]*` files plus the `<file_argument>` provided through `xargs` to target location. And you execute this command 6 times.

---

What you want is first to find the `[ace]*` files, to get the first 6 of them (as you do with `head`) and to write the last command without the file to be copied, this argument will be provided from `xargs`.

```
find . -type f -name "[ace]*" | head -6 | xargs cp -t /target_loc
```

Now this was wrong or at least not safe, as will not handle for example filenames with spaces. So you can use this syntax:

```
find . -type f -name "[ace]*" | head -6 | xargs -I{} cp {} -t /target_loc
```

`-I` sets the replacement string so when this exists later, it means position of a quoted argument.